# How to image swap using forms and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to make a image swapping code using a form with 2 drop-down options.

Its for color options for a item call it a widget, a exterior and interior color. I've been scratching my head on approaching this and made this code.

Here is my HTML

```
<img id="Imageholder" src="../images/placeholder.jpg" />
<form>
Interior Color:
<select name="covers">
<option value="or1">Orange</option>
<option value="be1">Blue</option>
<option value="rd1">Red</option>
<option value="bk1">Black</option>
<option value="gm1">GunMetal</option>
</select>
<p>Exterior Color:
<select name="wheels">
<option value="or2">Orange</option>
<option value="be2">Blue</option>
<option value="rd2">Red</option>
<option value="bk2">Black</option>
<option value="gm2">GunMetal</option>
</select></p>
<button onclick="function(Imagechange)">Change</button>
</form>
```

and here is my JS

```
// Place Holder
var Pholder = document.getElementById("Imageholder");
// The List
var Imglist = [ 
"Http://../images/imageOrOr.jpg,
Http://../images/imageOrBe.jpg,
Http://../images/imageOrRd.jpg,"
  ];
  // List Values
  var covers, wheels;
  // Interior Variables
 var be1, rd1, bk1, gm1, or1;
 // Exterior Variables
 var be2, rd2, bk2, gm2, or2;

function Imagechange () {
switch (covers,wheels) {
 case 0:
 if (covers = or1, wheels = or2) {
  Document.getElementbyId(Pholder) == Imglist[0];
 }
     break;
 case 1:
 if (covers = or1, wheels = be2) {
  Document.getElementbyId(Pholder) == Imglist[1];
 }
    break;
 case 2:

    break;
 }
}
```

Not the whole thing but I think this should be enough to get what I'm trying to do.

Unfortunately doesn't work with the proper links and everything so I'm not sure what is wrong.

Ultimately I want is when people pick the 2 options and click the button the image will appear above it, and when changing options and click again change the picture to the options they selected.

My knowledge of JavaScript is limited and equally the same with jquery but any ways to make this work or a better way would help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just so I have the idea right, depending on the combination of options selected, an appropriate image should replace the current image in the "Imageholder" Right??

If so, the code below should prove helpful for you. I didn't do all of the options, but you should get the idea. So when orange is selected in both select boxes and the button is clicked, the image will change to the desired image. You can then propagate this idea through all the combos, and have them switch out the image depending on the combo selected. You will need to include the jQuery library in your code to be able to use this.

I have put a jsFiddle link on the bottom that you can check out. Good luck!

```
<img id="Imageholder" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg" width="300" height="300"/>
<form>
Interior Color:
<select name="covers" id="covers">
<option value="or1">Orange</option>
<option value="be1">Blue</option>
<option value="rd1">Red</option>
<option value="bk1">Black</option>
<option value="gm1">GunMetal</option>
</select>
<p>Exterior Color:
<select name="wheels" id="wheels">
<option value="or2">Orange</option>
<option value="be2">Blue</option>
<option value="rd2">Red</option>
<option value="bk2">Black</option>
<option value="gm2">GunMetal</option>
</select></p>
<button id="changeBtn">Change</button>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() { 

    $('#changeBtn').click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();

    var newImage = 'http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/magic-of-blue-universe-images.jpg'

        if(($('#covers').val() == 'or1') && ($('#wheels').val() == 'or2')){
            $('img').attr('src', newImage);
        }

        else {
            alert('error')
        }

    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/w61g5L7o/6/)

Comment: Thank you this works pretty well I can still use the array list while doing a very long else if statement but I can at least get this running and embedded into the site soon after completion and testing.

Comment: Cool, glad it will work for you. There may be more efficient way than multiple if statements, but this will get it working for you. Then you can try and optimize down the road if you think of a cleaner implementation for that part.